# Automate cohort analysis in database

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to perform cohort analysis for subscriptions and fetch the report for it. Suppose in January, there were 100 subscriptions and in February, out of those 100 only 80 are active, in March out of those initial 100 subs only 50 are active and in April only 30 remain.
I want to store this data in Oracle db and keep on adding the data month on month. What would be the best approach?

[image]

Using materialised view could be used but it has restriction on current date. Please suggest some approach I can use.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a CSV [code block] or table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right and if your data are (or could be) similar to this:

```sql
WITH          -- Sample data
    tbl  AS
        (   Select 1 "ID", To_Date('12.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ACT_DATE", 'ACTIVATION' "ACT_TYPE" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2, To_Date('19.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVATION' From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 3, To_Date('19.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVATION' From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 4, To_Date('19.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVATION' From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 5, To_Date('19.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVATION' From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 1, To_Date('12.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVITY'   From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 1, To_Date('31.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVITY'   From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 3, To_Date('13.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVITY'   From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2, To_Date('17.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVITY'   From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 6, To_Date('17.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVATION' From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 7, To_Date('19.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVATION' From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 1, To_Date('10.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVITY'   From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2, To_Date('12.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVITY'   From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 6, To_Date('27.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVITY'   From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 6, To_Date('10.04.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ACTIVITY'   From Dual
        ),

        ID ACT_DATE  ACT_TYPE 
---------- --------- ----------
         1 12-JAN-23 ACTIVATION 
         2 19-JAN-23 ACTIVATION 
         3 19-JAN-23 ACTIVATION 
         4 19-JAN-23 ACTIVATION 
         5 19-JAN-23 ACTIVATION 
         1 12-FEB-23 ACTIVITY   
         1 31-JAN-23 ACTIVITY   
         3 13-FEB-23 ACTIVITY   
         2 17-FEB-23 ACTIVITY   
         6 17-FEB-23 ACTIVATION 
         7 19-FEB-23 ACTIVATION 
         1 10-MAR-23 ACTIVITY   
         2 12-MAR-23 ACTIVITY   
         6 27-MAR-23 ACTIVITY   
         6 10-APR-23 ACTIVITY
```

... then you could create a cte (named it grid) to reflect the structure of your expected result:

```sql
  grid AS
    ( SELECT    t1.ACTIVATION_MONTH, t1.RN_1, t2.ACT_MONTH, t2.RN_2
      FROM      ( Select      To_Char(t.ACT_DATE, 'MON-yy') "ACTIVATION_MONTH", 
                              To_Char(t.ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') "RN_1"
                  From        tbl t
                  Where       ACT_TYPE = 'ACTIVATION'
                  Group By    To_Char(t.ACT_DATE, 'MON-yy'), To_Char(t.ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm')
                  Order By    To_Char(t.ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm')
                ) t1
      LEFT JOIN ( Select      To_Char(t.ACT_DATE, 'MON-yy') "ACT_MONTH", 
                              To_Char(t.ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') "RN_2"
                  From        tbl t 
                  Group By    To_Char(t.ACT_DATE, 'MON-yy'), To_Char(t.ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm')
                  Order By    To_Char(t.ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm')
                ) t2 ON(t2.RN_2 >= t1.RN_1)
    )
--
--  grid result
ACTIVATION_MONTH RN_1   ACT_MONTH RN_2 
---------------- ------ --------- ------
JAN-23           202301 JAN-23    202301 
JAN-23           202301 FEB-23    202302 
JAN-23           202301 MAR-23    202303 
JAN-23           202301 APR-23    202304 
FEB-23           202302 FEB-23    202302 
FEB-23           202302 MAR-23    202303 
FEB-23           202302 APR-23    202304
```

... And now you could use RN_1 as ACTIVATIONS condition maker and RN_2 (or both) for ACTIVITIES.
Main SQL

```sql
SELECT  g.ACTIVATION_MONTH, g.ACT_MONTH, 
        CASE WHEN g.RN_1 = g.RN_2 
             THEN ( Select Count(Distinct ID) 
                    From tbl 
                    Where ACT_TYPE = 'ACTIVATION' And To_Char(ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') = g.RN_1) 
        ELSE  ( Select Count(Distinct ID) 
                    From tbl 
                    Where ACT_TYPE = 'ACTIVITY' And 
                          To_Char(ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') = g.RN_2 And 
                          ID IN(SELECT ID FROM TBL WHERE ACT_TYPE =  'ACTIVATION' And To_Char(ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') = g.RN_1))
        END "ACTIVE_SUBS"
FROM grid g
--  
--  R e s u l t :
ACTIVATION_MONTH ACT_MONTH ACTIVE_SUBS
---------------- --------- -----------
JAN-23           JAN-23              5 
JAN-23           FEB-23              3 
JAN-23           MAR-23              2 
JAN-23           APR-23              0 
FEB-23           FEB-23              2 
FEB-23           MAR-23              1 
FEB-23           APR-23              1
```

Additional notes:
The grid cte generates the structure of activation months (JAN and FEB) followed by the following months until the last one in the data.
Main SQL, following the grid structure, counts IDs that are activated within the month where (RN_1 = RN_2 ===> JAN = JAN or FEB = FEB) so these rows in column ACTIVE_SUBS show number of activations. The rest of the act months (having same activation month) show number of still active IDs that are activated within the activation month.
Maybe a list of activated and still active IDs could help. Below is the same main SQL with two newly added columns showing the lists.

```sql
SELECT  g.ACTIVATION_MONTH, 
        ( Select Distinct LISTAGG(Distinct ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By ID) OVER() "ID_LIST_ACTIVATED" 
                    From tbl 
                    Where ACT_TYPE = 'ACTIVATION' And To_Char(ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') = g.RN_1) "ACTIVATED_IDS",
        --
        g.ACT_MONTH, 
        CASE WHEN g.RN_1 = g.RN_2 
             THEN ( Select Count(Distinct ID) 
                    From tbl 
                    Where ACT_TYPE = 'ACTIVATION' And To_Char(ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') = g.RN_1) 
        ELSE  ( Select Count(Distinct ID) 
                    From tbl 
                    Where ACT_TYPE = 'ACTIVITY' And 
                          To_Char(ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') = g.RN_2 And 
                          ID IN(SELECT ID FROM TBL WHERE ACT_TYPE =  'ACTIVATION' And To_Char(ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') = g.RN_1))
        END || ' IDs' "ACTIVE_SUBS",
        --
        (Select Distinct LISTAGG(Distinct ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By ID) OVER() "ID_LIST_ACTIVE"
                    From tbl 
                    Where ACT_TYPE = 'ACTIVITY' And 
                          To_Char(ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') = g.RN_2 And 
                          ID IN(SELECT ID FROM TBL WHERE ACT_TYPE =  'ACTIVATION' And To_Char(ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') = g.RN_1)) "ACTIVE_IDS"
FROM grid g
--  
--  R e s u l t :
ACTIVATION_MONTH  ACTIVATED_IDS  ACT_MONTH  ACTIVE_SUBS  ACTIVE_IDS
----------------  -------------  ---------  -----------  --------------------
JAN-23            1, 2, 3, 4, 5  JAN-23     5   IDs        1
JAN-23            1, 2, 3, 4, 5  FEB-23     3   IDs        1, 2, 3
JAN-23            1, 2, 3, 4, 5  MAR-23     2   IDs        1, 2
JAN-23            1, 2, 3, 4, 5  APR-23     0   IDs
FEB-23            6, 7           FEB-23     2   IDs
FEB-23            6, 7           MAR-23     1   IDs         6
FEB-23            6, 7           APR-23     1   IDs         6
```

UPDATE:
To avoid using IN clause you could try to create 2 more cte-s like here:

```sql
  activations AS
        ( Select To_Char(ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') "ACT_DATE", ID From tbl Where ACT_TYPE = 'ACTIVATION' ),
  activities AS
        ( Select a.ACT_DATE "ACT_DATE_1", To_Char(a1.ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') "ACT_DATE_2", a1.ID 
          From tbl a1 
          Left Join activations a ON(a.ID = a1.ID And a.ACT_DATE != To_Char(a1.ACT_DATE, 'yyyymm') )
          Where a1.ACT_TYPE = 'ACTIVITY' )
```

... and change the main SQL to:

```sql
SELECT  g.ACTIVATION_MONTH, g.ACT_MONTH,
        CASE WHEN g.RN_1 = g.RN_2 
             THEN (Select Count(ID) From activations Where ACT_DATE = g.RN_1) 
        ELSE  (Select Count(Distinct ID) From activities Where ACT_DATE_1 = g.RN_1 And ACT_DATE_2 = g.RN_2)
        END "ACTIVE_SUBS"
FROM grid g
Order By g.RN_1, g.RN_2
```

Comment: That's a spot on! Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for. Just one quick question, count that is deduced in when..then, I want to use that in else part. As I want to calculate, the active subs. Your result is giving output for disconnections. If you can please help me with that

Comment: @dev Not quite sure what you are trying  to achieve. Please read additional notes (just posted) where I'm trying to explain the logic behind the answer. Will be glad to help you finish this if I get it right.

Comment: @d r This explanation is helpful. There are two things: 1. I'm trying to avoid 'IN' as I've more than 1M rows. 2. I've a column of disconnection_date for a subscription, which are moved to archive table using scheduler. So, I can get the count of disconnections from archive table and subtract it from the total active counts. This will give me active subs left.

Comment: @dev Just posted an update with the code not using IN clauses. Not sure if it would help, though.